# MDL - Text field not working when loading view with $.get()

Tags: jquery, material-design, material-design-lite

I'm using material design lite and i'm creating a popup through a get() jquery method. When i get the popup elements the mdl text field clicks don't work. But if i load the popup when page load work well.

I'm loading de css files and js. I think the problem is loading elements after js load but how can i solve that? I did that in the past and don't had this problem.

After loading the popup i don't have any error in console.

```
 function create(){
 $( "#create" ).click(function(e)
 {
   e.preventDefault();
   var linkPopup = $(this).attr('data-popup');
   $.get(linkPopup, function(response)
   {
      $( ".opacity" ).css("display","block");
      $( ".popup" ).css("display","block");
      $('.popup').html(response);
      $(".popup-close i").click(function()
      {
         $( ".popup .mdl-card" ).remove();
         $( ".popup" ).css("display","none");
         $( ".opacity" ).css("display","none");
      });
   });
 });
}
```

SOLUTION:
I have to add this line to upgrade the DOM because not recognize the elments loaded after.

```
 componentHandler.upgradeDom();
```

Thank's

Comment: Either attach event handlers after elements are loaded to DOM or delegate events after attaching to some parent element.

Comment: I do that and the click works but when i click out of element don't return to the initial state.

$( "#input-name" ).click(function(event)
          {
              $(this).parent().addClass("is-upgraded is-focused");
          });
there is a better solution? because mdl already have it done, just not to give to be charging the view later.
@sabithpocker

Answer (score 0):

Attach event handlers after the dynamic HTML is added to DOM.

```
$.get( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
  $( ".result" ).html( data );
  //attach click event handlers here
  create();
});
```

Or attach event handlers to parent and delegate using [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)  So only the parent element to wchcih event is attached should be present at the time of attaching event, `#create` can be added later and click event will work on it by delegation.

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", "#create", function() {
  //click event triggered
});
```

Comment: what is the click handler in material design lite to text fields?